# Acessing an object propery with array bracket notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to access a specific property in an object. Using an array for example

```
let array = ["tom","tony", "jerry"];

let object = {
  tony: "Brother", 
  tom: "Uncle", 
  jerry: "Cousin", 
};

object.array[1];
```

I'm trying to access object.tony but what happens is that it returns object."tony" instead.

The problem is that it returns it as a string so it causes an error.

Is it possible to return array[1] not as a string?

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: The language is javascript thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `object.array[1]`, JS will think your looking for `array` inside `object`, which does not exist. If an array was *in* the object, it would work:

```js
let object = {
    array: ["tom", "tony", "jerry"],
    // some other stuff...
};
console.log(object.array[1]);
```

You can use brackets instead:

```js
object[array[1]];
```

Example:

```js
let array = ["tom","tony", "jerry"];
let object = { tony: "Brother", tom: "Uncle", jerry: "Cousin", };
console.log(object[array[1]]);
```